# Model a Table that depends on a set of values in referenced table that can or not be present at the same time

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a table  'medical_observations' that in one field references other table 'sypstoms_at_arriving' that describes a list of possible symptoms.

```
    CREATE TABLE `patients`(
      id_patient   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      name         VARCHAR(25)  ,
      address      VARCHAR(50) ,
      CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_Patient` UNIQUE (`id_patient`)           
);
INSERT INTO `patients` values (1,'joe','joe´s address');
INSERT INTO `patients` values (2,'moe','moe´s address');
INSERT INTO `patients` values (3,'karl','karle´s address');
INSERT INTO `patients` values (4,'lenny','lenny´s address');




CREATE TABLE `symptoms_at_arrival` (
       symptom_at_arrival varchar(30) primary key
     );

INSERT INTO `symptoms_at_arrival` values ('vomit');
INSERT INTO `symptoms_at_arrival` values ('urine');
INSERT INTO `symptoms_at_arrival` values ('dizziness');
INSERT INTO `symptoms_at_arrival` values ('convulsion');



CREATE TABLE `medical_observations`(
      id_medical_observation   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      id_patient               INTEGER  NOT NULL,
      symptom_at_arrival       VARCHAR(30),  
      FOREIGN KEY (id_patient)            references `patients`             (id_patient),
      FOREIGN KEY (symptom_at_arrival)    references `symptoms_at_arrival` (symptom_at_arrival ),
      CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_medical_Observation` UNIQUE (`id_medical_observation`,`id_patient`)           
    );
```

My doubt is how to model or store th case when patient has  several symptoms... and not just one.
If that would be the case the name of symptom would be enough...

But if patient show several symptoms at the same time?

## Update

I have done a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c228), I was thinking to add a kind of table with 1's and 0's representing if patient shows certain symptom... Would that be correct?

Comment: "But if patient show several symptoms at the same time" - probably going to turn into a zombie. BTW, your title seems to bear no relation to the question you asked.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a Patient table as well.  Relationship between Patient and Medical_Observations should be 1-to-many (or many-to-many if it will have multiple observations per patient).  Your Symptoms table should have symptom_id field.

Comment: I have done a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c228 , but why is it important to add symptom_id field?, I was thinking to add a kind of table with 1's and 0's representing if patient shows certain symptom... Would that be correct?

Comment: Please post what kind of reports (results) you expect to produce from these tables.

Comment: I would like  to get all information of observation and patient, and if patient showed any kind of symptom... like name,address, a list of symptoms if any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make connection in the foreign keys

```
|patient|        |medical_observations|              |symptoms_at_arriving|
---------        ----------------------              ----------------------
**id** 1 ----|   **id_medical_observation** |-----1  **id**
name         |-M **id_patient**             |        symptom_at_arrival
                 **symptom_at_arrival** M---|
```

Try this, don't have mysql here to test, making table multi primary key to support multiple symptoms at same time

```
    CREATE TABLE `symptoms_at_arriving` (
       id    integer not null primary key autoincrement,
       symptom_at_arrival varchar(30)
     );
     INSERT INTO `symptom_at_arrival' values ('vomit');
     INSERT INTO `symptom_at_arrival` values ('urine');
    INSERT INTO `symptom_at_arrival` values ('dizziness');
    INSERT INTO `symptom_at_arrival` values ('convulsion');

CREATE TABLE `medical_observations`(
      id_medical_observation   INTEGER  NOT NULL,
      id_patient               INTEGER  NOT NULL,
      symptom_at_arrival       integer not null,  
      FOREIGN KEY (id_patient)            references `patients`             (id_patient),
      FOREIGN KEY (symptom_at_arrival)    references `symptoms_at_arriving` (symptom_at_arrival,
      PRIMARY KEY (id_medical_observation, id_patient, symptom_at_arrival)
```

);

Comment: Is there a way to select which symptoms the patient presented?

Comment: This is a poor and non-standard solution. It's also wrong! Not my downvote.

Comment: yep, using inner join, something like patient inner join (medical_observations inner join symptoms_at_arriving)

Comment: as i said, couldn't test it or didn't understood the question correctly... @cMinor if you want i can delete this answer

Comment: Thanks for answering, the issue here is I do not know how to model a table like that...

Comment: Ok, will edit, i don't have a way to do it graphically but i think you'll understand.